# How can I get ubuntu save my WiFi password?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, server, password, wpa-supplicant

Each time I start lightdm, ubuntu pops up a box asking me for my WiFi password before I log in - I can log in without the password. How I can have ubuntu save the password and connect the WiFi automatically at boot?

Answer (score 2):

Click on the network indicator in the top right of the screen, and select `Edit Connections…` from the menu, then select the connection in the list, choose to edit it, switch to the `General` tab, and enable `All users may connect to this network` for the connection.

Comment: Did not work :-( What else can I do?